# Why does this JDialog flicker in Win7 when modal?

Tags: java, windows-7, flicker, java-7, jdialog

In Windows 7, and Java 1.7 (or if 1.6, comment-out the two lines indicated), create a NetBeans/Eclipse project named "test" with two classes, Test and DroppableFrame, and paste this code into it. And then run it.

If you run with modal = true, it flickers. If you run with modal = false, it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

```
// test.java
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test implements KeyListener, MouseListener
{
    public Test(boolean m_modal)
    {
        Dimension prefSize;
        Insets inset;
        Font fontLabel, fontInput, fontButtons;
        int buttonCenters, buttonBackoff, buttonWidth, buttonCount, thisButton, buttonTop;
        String caption;

        JLayeredPane m_pane;
        JLabel m_lblBackground;
        JScrollPane m_txtInputScroll;
        int m_width, m_height, m_actual_width, m_actual_height;
        boolean m_singleLineInput   = true;
        String m_caption            = "Sample Modal Input";

        m_width     = 450;
        m_height    = m_singleLineInput ? /*single line*/180 : /*multi-line*/250;
        m_frame     = new DroppableFrame(false);
        caption     = m_caption;
        m_frame.setTitle(caption);

        // Compute the actual size we need for our window, so it's properly centered
        m_frame.pack();
        Insets fi       = m_frame.getInsets();
        m_actual_width  = m_width  + fi.left + fi.right;
        m_actual_height = m_height + fi.top  + fi.bottom;
        m_frame.setSize(m_width  + fi.left + fi.right,
                        m_height + fi.top  + fi.bottom);

        prefSize = new Dimension(m_width  + fi.left + fi.right,
                                 m_height + fi.top  + fi.bottom);
        m_frame.setMinimumSize(prefSize);
        m_frame.setPreferredSize(prefSize);
        m_frame.setMinimumSize(prefSize);
        m_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        m_frame.setSize(m_width, m_height);
        m_frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);    // Center window
        m_frame.setLayout(null);                // We handle all redraws

        Container c = m_frame.getContentPane();
        c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        c.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        m_pane = new JLayeredPane();
        m_pane.setLayout(null);
        m_pane.setBounds(0, 0, m_width, m_height);
        m_pane.setVisible(true);
        m_pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        c.add(m_pane);

        // Set the background image
        m_lblBackground = new JLabel();
        m_lblBackground.setBounds(0, 0, m_width, m_height);
        m_lblBackground.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        m_lblBackground.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        m_lblBackground.setVisible(true);
        m_lblBackground.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        m_pane.add(m_lblBackground);
        m_pane.moveToFront(m_lblBackground);

        // Create the fonts
        fontLabel   = new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 20);
        fontInput   = new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 14);
        fontButtons = fontLabel;

        // Create the visible label contents
        JLabel m_lblLabel = new JLabel();
        m_lblLabel.setBounds(15, 52, 423, 28);
        m_lblLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        m_lblLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        m_lblLabel.setFont(fontLabel);
        m_lblLabel.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        m_lblLabel.setText("A sample input:");
        m_lblLabel.setVisible(true);
        m_pane.add(m_lblLabel);
        m_pane.moveToFront(m_lblLabel);

        // Create the input box
        if (m_singleLineInput)
        {   // It's a single-line input box
            m_txtInputSingleLine = new JTextField();
            m_txtInputSingleLine.setBounds(15, 85, 421, 25);
            m_txtInputSingleLine.setFont(fontInput);
            m_txtInputSingleLine.setText("Initial Value");
            m_txtInputSingleLine.setVisible(true);
            m_txtInputSingleLine.addKeyListener(this);
            m_pane.add(m_txtInputSingleLine);
            m_pane.moveToFront(m_txtInputSingleLine);

        } else {
            m_txtInput          = new JTextArea();
            m_txtInputScroll    = new JScrollPane(m_txtInput);
            m_txtInputScroll.setBounds(15, 83, 421, 100);
            m_txtInputScroll.setAutoscrolls(true);
            m_txtInputScroll.setVisible(true);
            m_txtInput.setFont(fontInput);
            m_txtInput.setLineWrap(true);
            m_txtInput.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            m_txtInput.setTabSize(2);
            m_txtInput.setText("Initial Value");
            m_txtInput.setVisible(true);
            m_pane.add(m_txtInputScroll);
            m_pane.moveToFront(m_txtInputScroll);
        }

        // Determine which buttons are specified
        buttonCount = 0;
        m_buttons = _CANCEL_BUTTON + _OKAY_BUTTON;
        if ((m_buttons & _NEXT_BUTTON) != 0)
        {
            m_btnNext = new JButton("Next");
            m_btnNext.setFont(fontButtons);
            m_btnNext.addMouseListener(this);
            inset = m_btnNext.getInsets();
            inset.left = 3;
            inset.right = 3;
            m_btnNext.setMargin(inset);
            m_pane.add(m_btnNext);
            m_pane.moveToFront(m_btnNext);
            ++buttonCount;
        }
        if ((m_buttons & _CANCEL_BUTTON) != 0)
        {
            m_btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
            m_btnCancel.setFont(fontButtons);
            m_btnCancel.addMouseListener(this);
            inset = m_btnCancel.getInsets();
            inset.left = 3;
            inset.right = 3;
            m_btnCancel.setMargin(inset);
            m_pane.add(m_btnCancel);
            m_pane.moveToFront(m_btnCancel);
            ++buttonCount;
        }
        if ((m_buttons & _ACCEPT_BUTTON) != 0)
        {
            m_btnAccept = new JButton("Accept");
            m_btnAccept.setFont(fontButtons);
            m_btnAccept.addMouseListener(this);
            inset = m_btnAccept.getInsets();
            inset.left = 3;
            inset.right = 3;
            m_btnAccept.setMargin(inset);
            m_pane.add(m_btnAccept);
            m_pane.moveToFront(m_btnAccept);
            ++buttonCount;
        }
        if ((m_buttons & _OKAY_BUTTON) != 0)
        {
            m_btnOkay = new JButton("Okay");
            m_btnOkay.setFont(fontButtons);
            m_btnOkay.addMouseListener(this);
            inset = m_btnOkay.getInsets();
            inset.left = 3;
            inset.right = 3;
            m_btnOkay.setMargin(inset);
            m_pane.add(m_btnOkay);
            m_pane.moveToFront(m_btnOkay);
            ++buttonCount;
        }

        // Determine the coordinates for each button
        buttonCenters   = (m_width / (buttonCount + 1));
        buttonWidth     = (int)((double)buttonCenters * 0.80);
        buttonBackoff   = (m_width / (buttonCount + 2)) / 2;

        // Position the buttons
        thisButton  = 1;
        buttonTop   = m_singleLineInput ? 130 : 200;
        if (m_btnNext != null)
        {   // Position and make visible this button
            m_btnNext.setBounds( + (thisButton * buttonCenters) - buttonBackoff, buttonTop, buttonWidth, 40);
            m_btnNext.setVisible(true);
            ++thisButton;
        }
        if (m_btnCancel != null)
        {   // Position and make visible this button
            m_btnCancel.setBounds((thisButton * buttonCenters) - buttonBackoff, buttonTop, buttonWidth, 40);
            m_btnCancel.setVisible(true);
            ++thisButton;
        }
        if (m_btnAccept!= null)
        {   // Position and make visible this button
            m_btnAccept.setBounds((thisButton * buttonCenters) - buttonBackoff, buttonTop, buttonWidth, 40);
            m_btnAccept.setVisible(true);
            ++thisButton;
        }
        if (m_btnOkay != null)
        {   // Position and make visible this button
            m_btnOkay.setBounds((thisButton * buttonCenters) - buttonBackoff, buttonTop, buttonWidth, 40);
            m_btnOkay.setVisible(true);
            ++thisButton;
        }

// The modal code causes some slow component rendering.
// Needs looked at to figure out why
        if (m_modal)
        {   // Make it a modal window
            m_frame.setModal(m_width, m_height, fi, m_pane);

        } else {
            // Make it a non-modal window
            m_frame.setVisible(true);
            m_frame.forceWindowToHaveFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        m_frame.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean modal = true;
        Test t = new Test(modal);
    }

    private DroppableFrame  m_frame;

    private int             m_buttons;
    private JTextField      m_txtInputSingleLine;
    private JTextArea       m_txtInput;
    private JButton         m_btnNext;
    private JButton         m_btnCancel;
    private JButton         m_btnAccept;
    private JButton         m_btnOkay;

    public static final int _NEXT_BUTTON    = 1;
    public static final int _CANCEL_BUTTON  = 2;
    public static final int _ACCEPT_BUTTON  = 4;
    public static final int _OKAY_BUTTON    = 8;
    public static final int _NEXT_CANCEL    = 3;
    public static final int _ACCEPT_CANCEL  = 6;
    public static final int _OKAY_CANCEL    = 10;
}


        // DroppableFrame.java
    package test;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.awt.dnd.*;
    import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
    import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
    import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
    import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class DroppableFrame extends JFrame
                                implements  DropTargetListener,
                                            DragSourceListener,
                                            DragGestureListener,
                                            ComponentListener
    {
        public DroppableFrame(boolean isResizeable)
        {
            super("JFrame");

            m_dragSource    = DragSource.getDefaultDragSource();
            m_dragSource.createDefaultDragGestureRecognizer(this, DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE, this);
            this.setDropTarget(new DropTarget(this, DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE, this));
            addComponentListener(this);

            m_isResizeable  = isResizeable;
            m_modal         = false;
            setResizable(isResizeable);
        }

        /**
         * Sets the frame to a modal state
         * @param width
         * @param height
         */
        public void setModal(int            width,
                             int            height,
                             Insets         fi,
                             JLayeredPane   m_pan)
        {
            int i;
            Component[] comps;
            Component c;
            Point p;

            m_modal         = true;
            m_modalDialog   = new Dialog((JFrame)null, getTitle(), true);
            m_modalDialog.setLayout(null);
            m_modalDialog.setResizable(m_isResizeable);
            m_modalDialog.setSize(width + fi.left + fi.right, height + fi.top + (fi.bottom * 2));
            m_modalDialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            m_modalDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            if (m_pan != null)
            {   // Add/copy the pane's components
                comps = m_pan.getComponents();
                if (comps != null)
                    for (i = 0; i < comps.length; i++)
                    {   // Add and reposition the component taking into account the insets
                        c = m_modalDialog.add(comps[i]);
                        p = c.getLocation();
                        c.setLocation(p.x + fi.left, p.y + fi.top + fi.bottom);
                    }
            }
            m_modalDialog.setVisible(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            Dimension d = getSize();
            Dimension m = getMaximumSize();

            boolean resize = d.width > m.width || d.height > m.height;
            d.width = Math.min(m.width, d.width);
            d.height = Math.min(m.height, d.height);
            if (resize)
            {
                Point p = getLocation();
                setVisible(false);
                setSize(d);
                setLocation(p);
                setVisible(true);
            }
            super.paint(g);
        }

        @Override
        public void dragDropEnd(DragSourceDropEvent DragSourceDropEvent){}

        @Override
        public void dragEnter(DragSourceDragEvent DragSourceDragEvent){}

        @Override
        public void dragExit(DragSourceEvent DragSourceEvent){}

        @Override
        public void dragOver(DragSourceDragEvent DragSourceDragEvent){}

        @Override
        public void dropActionChanged(DragSourceDragEvent DragSourceDragEvent){}

        @Override
        public void dragEnter (DropTargetDragEvent dropTargetDragEvent)
        {
            dropTargetDragEvent.acceptDrag(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
        }

        @Override
        public void dragExit (DropTargetEvent dropTargetEvent) {}

        @Override
        public void dragOver (DropTargetDragEvent dropTargetDragEvent) {}

        @Override
        public void dropActionChanged (DropTargetDragEvent dropTargetDragEvent){}

        @Override
        public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dropTargetDropEvent)
        {
            try
            {
                Transferable tr = dropTargetDropEvent.getTransferable();
                if (tr.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor))
                {
                    dropTargetDropEvent.acceptDrop (DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
                    java.util.List fileList = (java.util.List)tr.getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
                    Iterator iterator = fileList.iterator();
                    while (iterator.hasNext())
                    {
                        File file = (File)iterator.next();
                        if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml"))
                        {   // Do something with the file here

                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Ignored dropped file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                        }
                    }
                    dropTargetDropEvent.getDropTargetContext().dropComplete(true);

                } else {
                    dropTargetDropEvent.rejectDrop();

                }

            } catch (IOException io) {
                dropTargetDropEvent.rejectDrop();

            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ufe) {
                dropTargetDropEvent.rejectDrop();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent dragGestureEvent)
        {
        }

        public void setTranslucency(float opaquePercent)
        {
            try
            {
                if (System.getProperty("java.version").substring(0,3).compareTo("1.6") <= 0)
                {   // Code for translucency works in 1.6, raises exception in 1.7
                    Class awtUtilitiesClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
                    Method mSetWindowOpacity;
                    mSetWindowOpacity = awtUtilitiesClass.getMethod("setWindowOpacity", Window.class, float.class);
                    if (mSetWindowOpacity != null)
                    {
                        if (!m_modal)
                            mSetWindowOpacity.invoke(null, this, opaquePercent);
                    }

                } else {
// If compiling in 1.6 or earlier, comment-out these next two lines
                    if (!m_modal)
                        setOpacity(opaquePercent);
                }

            } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
            } catch (IllegalComponentStateException ex) {
            } catch (Throwable t) {
            } finally {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
        {
            Dimension d = getSize();
            Dimension m = getMaximumSize();

            boolean resize = d.width > m.width || d.height > m.height;
            d.width = Math.min(m.width, d.width);
            d.height = Math.min(m.height, d.height);
            if (resize)
                setSize(d);
        }

        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose()
        {
            if (m_modal)
            {
                m_modalDialog.setVisible(false);
                m_modalDialog = null;
            }
            super.dispose();
        }

        public void forceWindowToHaveFocus()
        {
            Rectangle bounds;
            Insets insets;
            Robot robot = null;

            if (m_modal)
                m_modalDialog.setVisible(true);
            setVisible(true);
            toFront();

            bounds = getBounds();
            insets = getInsets();

            try {
                robot = new Robot();
                robot.mouseMove(bounds.x + bounds.width / 2, bounds.y + insets.top / 2);
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

            } catch (AWTException ex) {
            }
        }

        protected DragSource            m_dragSource;
        protected boolean               m_isResizeable;
        protected boolean               m_modal;
        protected Dialog                m_modalDialog;
    }
```

Comment: @mre: first `s` in `sscce` stands for short. Sorry, but I don't see short here.

Comment: I tried your code in Eclipse and Java 1.6.0_21, and it does not flicker when `modal` is set to `true`. However, you call methods which are not available (`setOpacity` on `Dialog`). Which version of Java are you testing this with?

Comment: 1.7, and this is a small portion of the code that it comes from (obviously), but it replicates the failure succinctly. I haven't tested it in 1.6.0_25, which I have, but will do so now.

Comment: @Laf: this method is from java 7

Comment: It flickers notably less in 1.6, but when I type input into the text box, it flickers. If I mouse over the buttons, you can see them being rendered, as if the paint operation is drawing the background, or drawing layers slowly giving it a flickering appearance.

Comment: Code has been edited to fix that part. Note: The modal code is new, and I haven't finished developing or testing it because of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're adding Swing components to an AWT `Dialog`. This will definitely cause problems. Using `JDialog` seems to remove the flickering.

Comment: Absolutely right. I thought it was JDialog all this time. So much for seeing with my eyes. :-) Thank you, Denis.

Comment: @RickHodgin: you're welcome. But what you are doing in this code is very bad practice. Why don't you change your JFrame into a JDialog?

Comment: @Rick Hodgin and then you have to change `paint(Graphics g)` to the `paintComponent(Graphics g)`

Comment: It's a generic frame class used by several classes, one that I'm adding a modal option to. What is very bad practice about it?

Comment: @RickHodgin: Copying components to a dialog just to create a modal dialog, using absolute layout, whatever dark magic you're doing in `paint()`.

Comment: The paint() code is interesting. I needed a way to make the DroppableFrame class (JFrame) resize without quirky flickering as well. I searched and found no solutions, but I made a solution (that I've posted here somewhere, see my name link), where I use JNI and native calls to Windows to hook the HWND's WndProc() and setup and intercept some things during the resize operations. This keeps the control completely smooth while resizing, and the paint calls coordinate some of that resizing with that external functionality.

Comment: The components copied to the dialog with absolute layout are because I know in this case, the original m_frame, m_pan and m_frame.getContentPane() will never be shown, so they become a type of array which was setup for the original non-modal function, and then here become source data for deposition onto the JDialog modal frame. Make sense? Basically, it's extending the original code base, which is widely in use, with a new functionality, trying to break as little as possible.